# GetX Observe List while updating it is a weird Loop

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-getx

Currently I'm trying to observe a `ListView.Builder` using the `Obx()`. Lets say I have a textfield inside that list item, and I'm trying to observe the changes of the inputs, I'm getting a weird cycle / loop where by for every letter I typed will just updates / reset the list item.

Any Ideas how i could observe the Entire list while also being reactive to the inputs of the list items?

**ViewWithGetx**

```
     Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = controller.links[index];
              return Padding(
                key: Key(item.id),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                child: LinkItem(
                  id: item.id,
                  index: index,
                  linkName: item.linkName,
                  onPressDelete: () {
                    controller.deleteLink(item.id);
                  },
                  onLinkNameChanged: (input) {
                    controller.updateLinkName(item.id, input);
                  },
                  onLinkURLChanged: (input) {},
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: controller.links.length,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**Controller**

````
  final _user = User().obs;
  var isAddingLinkData = false.obs;

  User get user => _user.value;
  String get id => _user().id;
  String get email => _user().email;
  List<Link> get links => _user().links;

  late var linkNameTextController = TextEditingController();
  late var linkURLTextController = TextEditingController();

  refreshData() {
    _user.refresh();
  }
}

extension LinkForm on FormController {
  addNewLink() {
    // isAddingLinkData.value = true;
    _user().links.add(Link.createEmpty());
    refreshData();
  }

  cancelAddNewLink() {
    // isAddingLinkData.value = false;
  }

  saveNewLink() {
    var newLink = Link.createEmpty();
    _user().links.add(newLink);
    isAddingLinkData.value = false;
    refreshData();
    clearLinkTextController();
  }

  updateLinkName(String id, String input) {
    int index = links.indexWhere((e) => e.id == id);
    if (links.isContainsIndex(index)) {
      links[index].linkName = input;
      refreshData();
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember I have read that a stateless widget tends to reset the text field. To avoid that call the

> TextEditingController()

in controller and call it in.